# inverse CDF and symmetrical distribution

Tags: inverse, cumulative-distribution-functions

Let's assume you are having a symmetric distribution and the following information:
\begin{align} 
F^{-1}(x)=a
\end{align}
How to mathematically solve the following equation
\begin{align} 
F^{-1}(1-x)=\:?
\end{align}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering that the first equation is

$$x=P(A\leq a)$$

Using symmetry you get

$$F^{-1}(1-x)=-a$$

Comment: Thank you. First equation is trivial. After that you multiply both sides by -1 add 1 and take $F^{-1}()$. So is $F^{-1}(1)=0$?

Comment: So the question is how to go from $F^{-1}(1-F(a))$ to $-a$?

Comment: I answer myself here: Because $1-F(a)=F(-a)$ you get $F^{-1}(F(-a))=-a$.